# Rules 'Execute custom PHP code' to set DB Values

Tags: rules

I wish to use rules to set some values in my database. I have the following php code working correctly as a function called when cron is run:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter
*/
function custom_reset_page_logs_cron() {
   // GROWTH
   // UPDATE field_data_field_growth_pageviews SET field_growth_pageviews_value = 0;
   $growth_updated = db_update('field_data_field_growth_pageviews')
   ->fields(array('field_growth_pageviews_value' => 0))
   ->execute();

   // EXPORT
   // UPDATE field_data_field_export_pageviews SET field_export_pageviews_value = 0;
   $export_updated = db_update('field_data_field_export_pageviews')
   ->fields(array('field_export_pageviews_value' => 0))
   ->execute();

   // INVESTMENT
   // UPDATE field_data_field_investment_pageviews SET field_investment_pageviews_value = 0;
   $investment_updated = db_update('field_data_field_investment_pageviews')
   ->fields(array('field_investment_pageviews_value' => 0))
   ->execute();

   // EXPORT
   // UPDATE field_data_field_workforce_pageviews SET field_workforce_pageviews_value = 0;
   $workforce_updated = db_update('field_data_field_workforce_pageviews')
   ->fields(array('field_workforce_pageviews_value' => 0))
   ->execute();
}
```

However I want this code to run on a rule, rather than on a cron run. I would have thought that it is straightforward to add this to a PHP rule using 'Execute custom PHP code. However when I paste the following into a rule, and trigger the rule nothing happens:

```
   // GROWTH
   // UPDATE field_data_field_growth_pageviews SET field_growth_pageviews_value = 0;
   $growth_updated = db_update('field_data_field_growth_pageviews')
   ->fields(array('field_growth_pageviews_value' => 0))
   ->execute();

   // EXPORT
   // UPDATE field_data_field_export_pageviews SET field_export_pageviews_value = 0;
   $export_updated = db_update('field_data_field_export_pageviews')
   ->fields(array('field_export_pageviews_value' => 0))
   ->execute();

   // INVESTMENT
   // UPDATE field_data_field_investment_pageviews SET field_investment_pageviews_value = 0;
   $investment_updated = db_update('field_data_field_investment_pageviews')
   ->fields(array('field_investment_pageviews_value' => 0))
   ->execute();

   // EXPORT
   // UPDATE field_data_field_workforce_pageviews SET field_workforce_pageviews_value = 0;
   $workforce_updated = db_update('field_data_field_workforce_pageviews')
   ->fields(array('field_workforce_pageviews_value' => 0))
   ->execute();
```

I have set a second action to 'Show a message on the site' and this is being shown, so it is clear that the rule is being run. I am clearing the cache before I check the database values.

Any ideas why my action isn't working? Thanks

Comment: After some more investigation I have realized that the code is working, to a certain extent. The fields to be updated are fields on the user profile. The rules actually works to update the fields for every user except the user who triggered the rule. The rule is triggered by viewing a page. I am guessing that if i schedule the rule rather than have it triggered by a pageview it should work correctly

Answer (score 0):

Actually the above code works for every user except the user triggering the rule. Scheduling the rule rather than having it activated by a pageview means it is applied to all users